# Is there any way to make this code shorter ? stem subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, subplot

x and y-axis variables in the stem plots are the columns from the DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1,figsize=(8,20))
fig.suptitle('Magnitude-Time Plot : R1')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

# Defining custom 'xlim' and 'ylim' values.
xlim = (1990, 2005)
ylim = (0, 9)

# Setting the values for all axes.
plt.setp(ax, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

    # plot with no marker

#subplot(311) : Catalog8 in R1
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax[0].stem(cata8q1.YearDeci,cata8q1.Magnitude, markerfmt=' ',use_line_collection=True,linefmt='b')
plt.setp(stemlines,linewidth=0.5)
ax[0].set_title('Catalog OLD')

#subplot(312) : catalog 9 _Uniq in R1
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax[1].stem(cata9uniq1.YearDeci,cata9uniq1.Magnitude, markerfmt=' ',use_line_collection=True,linefmt='r')
plt.setp(stemlines,linewidth=0.5)
ax[1].set_title('Unique events in NEW CATALOG')

#subplot(312) : Catalog NEW in R1
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax[2].stem(catanewq1.YearDeci,catanewq1.Magnitude, markerfmt=' ',use_line_collection=True)
plt.setp(stemlines,linewidth=0.5)
ax[2].set_title('OLD + unique events in NEW Catalog')

plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot the [3,1] stem subplots, I want to control the axes properties and figure properties more handy , with less number of lines of code

Comment: you could try to create function with code which you reapeat and run this function with different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```py
catalogs = [(cata8q1,"Catalog Old", "b"), ...] 

for i, (catalog, title, linefmt) in enumerate (catalogs):
    markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax[0].stem(catalog.YearDeci,catalog.Magnitude, markerfmt=' ',use_line_collection=True,linefmt=linefmt)   
     plt.setp(stemlines,linewidth=0.5) 
     ax[i].set_title(title)
```

Comment: @VGB if it's work for you, please feel free to validate this awser.